# Where does the syntax for expressions in SSRS come from?

Tags: reporting-services, syntax

The syntax for the expressions in SSRS seem to be very different to the other products that Microsoft produces.

For example, I am not aware of any other tool that uses IIF() for an if statement and using 'is nothing' to assess if value is NULL.

Is there any history of where this syntax came from or a reason for why it is in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSRS expressions are based on Visual Basic.

> Expressions are written in Microsoft Visual Basic, and can use
>   built-in functions, custom code, report and group variables, and
>   user-defined variables. Expressions begin with an equal sign (=).

Source: [Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

The [IIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function is "inherited" from VB, same goes for is nothing.